# Accessing value in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript

I have a simple line of javascript, I managed to access the variable in the array but how do I just get the string of it "leave"?

```js
var person = {
  people: [{
    name: "jason"
  }, {
    name: "chowder"
  }, {
    name: "leave"
  }],
  lastname: "zhang"
};

console.log(person.people[2]);
```

Comment: `console.log(person.people[2].name);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the keyname (in this case 'name') after specifying the array index, since you've got an object containing an array of objects, containing key/value pairs.

```
person.people[2].name
```

...will give you what you want, since you want the value from the key called 'name'.

Comment: ** person.people[2].name

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the property of an index like so:

```
person.people[2].name
```

```js
var person = {
  people: [{
    name: "jason"
  }, {
    name: "chowder"
  }, {
    name: "leave"
  }],
  lastname: "zhang"
};

console.log(person.people[2].name);
```